# No mass in the Big Bang?

Tags: general-relativity

Roger Penrose says in the Big Bang there was no mass!!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OFqjA5ekmoY
because E=M.c2.  ( minute ca. 6).  So where came the mass from.

Comment: He says "there effectively was no mass" because the energy is so high that there is no sense of scale.

Answer (score 1):

The big bang was before the spontaneous symmetry breaking, so there was no massive particles.

Comment: While correct, it might be worth expanding a little on this

Answer (score 0):

Einstein's $E=mc^2$ : mass is equivalent to energy.  At the very beginning of the Big Bang, yes, everything was energy.  But as the universe expanded and cooled, particles with mass "condensed out" of the energy.

Just like today, in cosmic rays and particle accelerators, a gamma ray (energy) can spontaneously convert to an electron and positron (mass).

Answer (score 0):

The $E=mc^2$ comes from special relativity, and the m there is not an invariant as it is a function of velocity. What is invariant in special relativity is the "length" of [a four vector ,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) $(E,p_x,p_y,p_z)$ .

[image: fourvect]

> The length of this 4-vector is the rest energy of the particle. The invariance is associated with the fact that the rest mass is the same in any inertial frame of reference.

So the masses are not additive, the four vectors are, following four vector algebra. That is how two zero mass particles, (as are two photons) can have the mass of the pi0 meson.

In General Relativity  it is only at lower energies and flat spaces that special relativity concepts, like the invariant mass, can be used. One has the [stress energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor#Definition) and its algebra.